# Why do I have an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I don't understand why this code is creating an infinite loop.

```
for (var i = 8 ; i < 120; i+12) {
    console.log(i * 1);
}
```

If I make an assignment of `i` like `i = i + 12` then everything works like it should. Please explain what is going on here.

Comment: Its `i+=12`  not `i+12`

Comment: Yeah your increment isn't an increment at all.

Answer (score 2):

You'll learn that JavaScript does some wonky and questionable things...

I've never seen a use-case with the parameters you've set with a for loop, but I'm assuming you know the defaults.

Anyway, what you are doing is not increment i by 12, so it will continue to loop, given i never actually increases.

The operator += should do the trick, as it will take the previous value of i, and add 12 to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need `i += 12` to do assignment instead of just `i + 12` (which is a plain expression).

Answer (score 1):

because `i+12` does **not** `increment and store` the incremented value in `i`. So the value of `i` is always `8`. Wheras `i=i+12` increments and stores the value in `i` and the loop terminates when `i >= 120`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `i+=12` Check out the [operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) of JavaScript

```
for (var i = 8 ; i < 120; i +=12) {
    console.log(i * 1);
}
```